# How can I overscore a character?

Tags: symbols, characters, anki

I am using [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) to create flash cards for Boolean identities. I prefer to use an overscore as opposed to a prime for negated variables. Can this be accomplished with LaTeX?

**EDIT:** The header and footer are as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `$\overline{x}$`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Even though it may seem trivial, it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill, You've just highlighted how much I do not know about LaTeX.

Comment: I only started this journey earlier this year, so give it time... As a tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`). I took the liberty to format you post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As egreg mentioned in the comments, `\overline{x}` is a good solution. Here are various symbols that can be used for negation that I can think of:

```
   $x' \quad x^\prime \quad \overline{x} \quad \bar{x} \quad \lnot x \quad {\sim} x$
```

[image]

Also, for future reference, you should have a look at [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol).

Comment: Not `~\!\!`, but `{\sim}` that makes `{\sim}` into an ordinary symbol (it's a relation symbol, by itself)

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the solution to reflect this.

Answer (score 7):

If you're feeling a little more adventurous, the [`accents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/accents) allows you  to stack `<accent>` on `<stuff>` using

```
\accentset{<accent>}{<stuff>}
```

Here is a comparison between `\overline`, `\bar` and `\accentset` via the newly defined macro

```
\negbool[<thickness>]{<stuff>}
```

that puts a rule of thickness `<thickness>` (defaults to `0.4pt`) on `<stuff>`. It allows you a little more freedom and has a slightly better placement of the "overline" on it's slanted base:

[image: Accent comparison]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage{accents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/accents
\newcommand*{\negbool}[2][0.4pt]{\ensuremath{\accentset{\rule{\widthof{#2}}{#1}}{#2}}}
\begin{document}
$\overline{x} \quad \bar{x} \quad \negbool{x} \quad \negbool[1pt]{x}$
\end{document}
```