# How can I correct spacing issues?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, anki

When using the following code I get unsightly spaces (following the opening parentheses, after the `=` and between the `x`' and `y`'):

```
[$](\quad \overline{x+y})=\quad \overline{x}\quad \overline{y}[/$]
```

[image: Bad spacing]

What am I doing wrong?

If it helps, I am using Anki with its default header and footer settings:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Also, please forgive me if I am unclear or have duplicated a question; I am new to TeX and unfamiliar with the terminology.

Comment: That did the trick. I assumed that it was a requisite prefix to \overline. Cheers!

Comment: In the [previous example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32405/how-can-i-overscore-a-character/32407#32407), this was included merely to separate the difference instances of negation.

Comment: That made sense to me as soon as I read your comment to remove them, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX provides a number of ways to print skips (blanks, or whitespace):

```
\def\thinspace{\kern .16667em }
\def\negthinspace{\kern-.16667em }
\def\enspace{\kern.5em }
\def\enskip{\hskip.5em\relax}
\def\quad{\hskip1em\relax}
\def\qquad{\hskip2em\relax}
```

The above are in addition to using `\hspace{<len>}` that you can use to print whitespace of length `<len>`. In your specific example, `\quad` skips "forward" by exactly `1em`, which leaves the blank spaces you witness. Removing them leaves the correct typesetting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$(\overline{x+y})=\overline{x}\overline{y}$
\end{document}
```

With the introduction of some of these spaces, you can also improve the presentation by inserting (say) a `\thinspace` between the `x` and `y`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$(\overline{x+y})=\overline{x}\thinspace\overline{y}$
\end{document}
```

For completeness, here's a table from Herbert Voss' [`mathmode` document](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) that illustrates some of the well-known spacing techniques/commands (Section **11.2 Additional horizontal spacing**, Table 7, p 29):

[image]